# Firebase authentication SMTP with alias

Tags: firebase, email

I am using firebase authentication with magic link for email registrations.

When I set the smtp setting for my domain, I cannot set the alias only the sender address, so when I set it to say **noreply@google.com** with the username **andrew@yahoo.com**, it sends but as **andrew@yahoo.com** and not the alias.

How can I set my alias email address with the smtp settings for firebase authentication?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into it, i realised that i needed to add the domain alias to the email address and then it worked.

I used this guide, hopefully it will help someone else.

https://ellisbenus.com/web-design-columbia-mo/workaround-using-gmail-alias-forwarded-email-addresses/